# Is there a way to deserialize and serialize a field in a different way by using jsonschemapojo2?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jsonschema2pojo

Let's assume I have the following pojo

```
class pojo{
  String color;
}
```

I want to deserialize color like so:

```
{
 COLOR: "red"
}
```

and serialize color like so:

```
{
 color: "red"
}
```

Comment: So your schema says "COLOR", but you want your pojo field to be named color?

Comment: No. The response from somewhere comes as COLOR and want to create my response with color. I don't want to create one pojo for deserializing and one for serializing. It's time consuming. I just want to use one pojo for both tasks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the name of the property when serializing, you can use the `@JsonProperty` annotation like this  : `@JsonProperty("color1")`

LE: Now i've understood what you want. You can use @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES) to accept uppercase attributes.